# Both atoms and co-atoms in a lattice

Tags: examples-counterexamples, order-theory

Is there an example of a lattice (or just a poset) for which both atoms and co-atoms are useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: A. K. Steiner. On the lattice of topologies. In: Josef Novák (ed.): General Topology and its Relations to Modern Analysis and Algebra. He discusses the lattice of all topologies and (1) states that every topology on X is the supremum of the atoms, but that (2) the co-atoms also generate the lattice and have certain interesting properties which he discusses.